# Python's function readlines(n) behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've read [**the documentation**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), but what does `readlines(n)` do?  By `readlines(n)`, I mean `readlines(3)` or any other number.

When I run `readlines(3)`, it returns same thing as `readlines()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The optional argument should mean how many (approximately) bytes are read from the file. The file will be read further, until the current line ends:

```
readlines([size]) -> list of strings, each a line from the file.

Call readline() repeatedly and return a list of the lines so read.
The optional size argument, if given, is an approximate bound on the
total number of bytes in the lines returned.
```

Another quote:

> If given an optional parameter *sizehint*, it reads that many bytes from the file and enough more to complete a line, and returns the lines from that.

You're right that it doesn't seem to do much for small files, which is interesting:

```
In [1]: open('hello').readlines()
Out[1]: ['Hello\n', 'there\n', '!\n']

In [2]: open('hello').readlines(2)
Out[2]: ['Hello\n', 'there\n', '!\n']
```

One might think it's explained by the following phrase in the documentation:

> Read until EOF using readline() and return a list containing the lines thus read. If the optional sizehint argument is present, instead of reading up to EOF, whole lines totalling approximately sizehint bytes **(possibly after rounding up to an internal buffer size)** are read. Objects implementing a file-like interface may choose to ignore sizehint if it cannot be implemented, or cannot be implemented efficiently.

However, even when I try to read the file without buffering, it doesn't seem to change anything, which means some other kind of internal buffer is meant:

```
In [4]: open('hello', 'r', 0).readlines(2)
Out[4]: ['Hello\n', 'there\n', '!\n']
```

On my system, this internal buffer size seems to be around 5k bytes / 1.7k lines:

```
In [1]: len(open('hello', 'r', 0).readlines(5))
Out[1]: 1756

In [2]: len(open('hello', 'r', 0).readlines())
Out[2]: 28080
```

Comment: @user2013613 I'd love to, but I don't think using other languages here is a good idea.

Comment: @user2013613 Yep, it won't do anything as long as the file size is less than this "internal buffer".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the file, readlines(hint) should return a smaller set of lines.  From the documentation:

```
f.readlines() returns a list containing all the lines of data in the file. 
If given an optional parameter sizehint, it reads that many bytes from the file 
and enough more to complete a line, and returns the lines from that. 
This is often used to allow efficient reading of a large file by lines, 
but without having to load the entire file in memory. Only complete lines 
will be returned.
```

So, if your file has 1000s of lines, you can pass in say... 65536, and it will only read up to that many bytes at a time + enough to complete the next line, returning all the lines that are completely read.

Answer (score 1):

> It lists the **lines**, through which the given character size 'n' spans
>   starting from the current line.

Ex: In a *`text`* file, with content of

```
one
two
three
four
```

`open('text').readlines(0)` returns `['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', 'four\n']`

`open('text').readlines(1)` returns `['one\n']`

`open('text').readlines(3)` returns `['one\n']`

`open('text').readlines(4)` returns `['one\n', 'two\n']`

`open('text').readlines(7)` returns `['one\n', 'two\n']`

`open('text').readlines(8)` returns `['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n']`

`open('text').readlines(100)` returns `['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', 'four\n']`