# What does io.IOBase.readlines(hint) mean in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-2.6, readlines

from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines):

```
readlines(hint=-1)
    Read and return a list of lines from the stream. 
    hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: 
      no more lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all lines so far exceeds hint.
```

What's the real meaning of hint?

In some enviroments:

```
python3 -c 'from io import StringIO;print(StringIO(u"hello\n"*10).readlines(6));import sys;print(sys.version_info[0:3])'
['hello\n', 'hello\n']
(3, 3, 0)

python -c 'from io import StringIO;print(StringIO(u"hello\n"*10).readlines(6));import sys;print(sys.version_info[0:3])'
[u'hello\n', u'hello\n']
(2, 7, 2)

python -c 'from io import StringIO;print(StringIO(u"hello\n"*10).readlines(6));import sys;print(sys.version_info[0:3])'
[u'hello\n']
(2, 6, 6)
```

**Why more than 6 characters?**

[Some one said that depended on buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541010/pythons-function-readlinesn-behavior).

But in my machine, i can not unbuffer Text I/O.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
>>> open('/etc/hosts','r',3).readlines(3)
['##\n', '# Host Database\n']
>>> open('/etc/hosts','r',0).readlines(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O
>>>
```

Or is it a bug in this method?

---

2013/02/25 Updated:

I check the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/96f08a22f562/Lib/_pyio.py#l505)(from python 2.6/2.7/[3.x](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/96f08a22f562/Lib/_pyio.py#l505)), but I can not explain this:

```
def readlines(self, hint=None):
    """Return a list of lines from the stream.

    hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more
    lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all
    lines so far exceeds hint.
    """
    if hint is None or hint <= 0:
        return list(self)
    n = 0
    lines = []
    for line in self:
        lines.append(line)
        n += len(line)
        if n >= hint:
            break
    return lines
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the difference from StringIO and BytesIO(But I have no idea why):

First check this (python 2.7/3.3):

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from io import BytesIO,StringIO
>>> print(BytesIO(b'hello\n'*10).readlines(6))
['hello\n']
>>> print(StringIO(u'hello\n'*10).readlines(6))
[u'hello\n', u'hello\n']
>>>
```

The C source codes from StringIO and BytesIO link here:

[Modules/_io/iobase.c#l591](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/381de621ff6a/Modules/_io/iobase.c#l591)

```
620     while (1) {
621         PyObject *line = PyIter_Next(self);
622         if (line == NULL) {
623             if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
624                 Py_DECREF(result);
625                 return NULL;
626             }
627             else
628                 break; /* StopIteration raised */
629         }
630 
631         if (PyList_Append(result, line) < 0) {
632             Py_DECREF(line);
633             Py_DECREF(result);
634             return NULL;
635         }
636         length += PyObject_Size(line);
637         Py_DECREF(line);
638 
639         if (length > hint)
640             break;
641     }
```

---

[Modules/_io/bytesio.c#l380](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/381de621ff6a/Modules/_io/bytesio.c#l380)

```
413     while ((n = get_line(self, &output)) != 0) {
414         line = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(output, n);
415         if (!line)
416             goto on_error;
417         if (PyList_Append(result, line) == -1) {
418             Py_DECREF(line);
419             goto on_error;
420         }
421         Py_DECREF(line);
422         size += n;
423         if (maxsize > 0 && size >= maxsize)
424             break;
425     }
426     return result;
```

Comment: I think the difference is between the conditions `length > hint` and `size >= maxsize`. One stops only when the amount read is strictly greater than the requested amount, while the other will stop if the amount is hit exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented, hence not a bug:

> `buffering` is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass `0` to switch buffering off **(only allowed in binary mode)**, `1` to
>   select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > `1`
>   to indicate the size of a fixed-size chunk buffer.

To answer you question: **"Why more than 6 characters?"**

This is also documented: `readlines` always returns complete lines:

> hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more
>   lines will be read **if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all
>   lines so far exceeds hint**.

That means: read another **whole line**; if `total read size` > `hint`, then stop reading.

In your example, after reading the first `"hello"` the size is not yet exceeded, so the second line is read.

Comment: 'hello'+'\n' is six characters. There is something different between python 2.6 and python 2.7/3.x.

Comment: @imxylz It's 6, which doesn't _exceed_ the size of 6 :) Yeah, something is different in Python 2.6, but the docs say `totalling approximately sizehint bytes` so this is not guaranteed to be precise anyway.

Comment: Please check the source: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/96f08a22f562/Lib/_pyio.py#l505

Comment: @imxylz Hm, look identical to the 2.6 version [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/936621d33c38/Lib/io.py)... _And_ it says `>=`, not `>` there.

Comment: sorry. All the versions from 2.6 to 3.3 are "if n >= hint: break". why not the same result?

Comment: @imxylz To be honest, I have no idea.