# Python Reading List From File And Printing Back In Idle Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to read from a file, I'm getting an annoying error, I think it's got something to do with the list format of the variables but I'm not sure.

If anyone can help with with this issue that would be great.
I think it's also got something to do with \n being printed at the end of the list.

This is my code:

## Option 1

```
    def one():
        print ("")
        print ("You have chosen to read the file!")
        print ("")
        file = open("sentence.txt" , "r")
        words = file.readlines(1)
        nums = file.readlines(2)
        #Remove "\n"
        #This bit doesn't work, I'm not sure how to remove "\n" 

        #These were me trying to get rid of the "\n"
        #map(str.strip, words)
        #words = words.strip('\n')

        print(words)
        print (nums)
        print ("")
        #Reconstruct sentence here
```

Comment: You don't have list - you have string which looks like list converted to string. You have to change function which save that list in file.

Comment: `nums` is not list with numbers but with strings. you can't substract 1 from `i` which is string (or char). `print(i , type(i))`  to see what you have.

Comment: You have a few things wrong with this. 1) `readlines()` takes one argument and it takes number of bytes, not line number 2) you are trying to read the element in the returned list as if it where just a string 3) you are trying to use `i` as an int when it is a string

Comment: Could you use these in the correct terms in some example code, so I can get a better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

The function `file.readlines()` does not take an argument for the number of lines, it reads all the lines of the file at once.  (for the record, if you do pass an argument like `file.readlines(n)`, the argument `n` is a "hint" about the number of bytes to read...more info here at [Python's function readlines(n) behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541010/pythons-function-readlinesn-behavior))

```
   def one():
        print ("")
        print ("You have chosen to read the file!")
        print ("")
        file = open("sentence.txt" , "r")
        lines = file.readlines() # read all the lines into a list
        words = lines[0]
        nums = lines[1]
        #Remove "\n"
        #This bit doesn't work, I'm not sure how to remove "\n" 

        #These were me trying to get rid of the "\n"
        #map(str.strip, words)
        words = words.strip("\n][").replace("'", "").split(",")

        nums = nums.strip("\n][").replace("'", "").split(",")
        nums = list(map(int, numbers))  ## assuming you want to convert the string to integers, use this

        print(words)
        print (nums)
        print ("")
        #Reconstruct sentence here
        remade_sentence = ' '.join([words[i-1] for i in nums])  ## changed empty string to space to add spaces
        print (remade_sentence)

        file.close() ## also, make sure to close your file!
```

EDIT: I have updated the code to deal with `nums` being a list of strings.
EDIT 2: updating code to reflect @notevenwrong's method of removing brackets and quotes

EDIT 3:  Resimplifying...when I open my input file in a text editor, I literally see:

```
['the', 'dog', 'cat']
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

If that is not the right input, then this code may not work.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, any more suggestions?

Comment: @Tom my sugestion: first use `json` to save this list in more useful form. Then use `json` to read this list from file. Now you have useless text in file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with json any more suggestions or ways?

Comment: This is my error now:  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, my bad, I forgot the nums() was multiple lines of the file...I will fix.

Comment: @SirParselot: yes, that's correct...for parsing plain text, I rarely find that useful...an oversight on my part.

Comment: I have amended the code, now I get this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1,'

Comment: @Tom: I think there's something about your input file I don't understand.  I added what I think it looks like.  But if my post is correct, then the line `nums = nums.strip("\n][").replace("'", "").split(",")` (or the previous version of that) should have stripped away the square bracket from `'1[,'

Comment: @Tom: I have simplified the code again to parse just a single row of numbers.

Comment: It's working now, I get this in idle: "thethethe dogthe cat"  which is correct! How would i go around adding spaces between every  word?

Comment: Great!  I updated the example to add whitespace...very simple, just change the empty string to a space, like this: `" ".join(words)`

Comment: Thanks! you have been a great help with this and now I have learn't a thing or 2  :)

Answer (score 1):

What `file.readlines(1)` returns is a single element list, and the element is a string. What you want to do get the string itself and replace the '\n', '[', ']', etc.

Try
`words[0].strip("\n][").replace("'", "").split(",")`

Comment: This is the right answer for the particular issue of converting the words to a list of strings.  It doesn't handle the integer conversion of the numbers, so I will update my code accordingly (but give @notevenwrong an upvote pls)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception at [words[i-1], Because i is str and you can perform -: 'str' and 'int'.

```
>>> i = '1'
>>> i -1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#101>", line 1, in <module>
    i -1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

A quick fix should be-

```
remade_sentence = ''.join([words[int(i)-1] for i in nums])
```

Comment: I get the error:     remade_sentence = ''.join([words[int(i)-1] for i in nums])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]'

Comment: that means i is str which contain char like '[', some thing wrong with the way you reading the file.