# List index out of range (searched for answer, none work)

Tags: python-3.6

When i run this code

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
xp_levelup_save=f.readlines(3)
xp_levelup_save=[int(i.replace("\n", "")) for i in xp_levelup_save][2]
f.close()
print (xp_levelup_save)
```

but a error comes up "List index out of range" If the readlines is 2 and the [2] is [1] it works fine. Not sure why this is happening. Can anyone help me and find a fix. I've tried looking at mulitple other discussions but none 
seem to work with this code.
My text document looks like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: `readlines(3)` doesn't mean, what you think it means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541029/8881141 Just try it without an argument.

Comment: I read the page. I don't seem to understand, if you could, can i have an example

Comment: @MapeModep just use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.readlines(3)`

Comment: The `3` doesn't mean, it reads 3 lines, but 3 bytes and then finishes to read this line. For a short document like yours it is safe to read the whole document with `readlines()` and just iterate through the lines. You can easily see this, by printing out `xp_levelup_save` right after `readlines`.

Comment: Ok.Thanks alot that worked just fine

Comment: Please write that as an answer so i can close the discussion

Answer (score 0):

`f.readlines()` doesn't need an argument to retrieve the lines of a document. If you provide this optional argument like `f.readlines(n)`, Python reads it as "expect n bytes and finish the line". Depending on your text file, this could be one, two or even more lines.

To read the text file, just use

```
xp_levelup_save = f.readlines()
#resume with your code
```

where each line is stored as a string list element in your variable `xp_levelup_save`.

Or simply

```
xp_levelup_save = [int(i.replace("\n", "")) for i in f.readlines()][2]
```