# UnicodeDecodeError : position of the error

Tags: python, python-unicode

I often face the "UnicodeDecodeError" when I'm writing some calculating programs. It says for example :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 57: invalid continuation byte
```

My question is : how can I locate which word in my code causes the error ? I have no idea how to know were this 'position 57' is situated. And by the way, what means 'invalid continuation byte' ?

Thanks for the answers.

PS : this error comes from this code where I try to apply the 4th order Runge-Kutta method to the Lorenz equations :

```
# Auteur : Bastien Massion 
# NOMA : 13701700
# Date création fichier : 23 novembre 2018 18h24
# Date dernière modification : 23 novembre 2018 19h05

# Je jure que ceci est le fruit de mon travail personnel

from numpy import *

def lorfunction(t, u): # u = [u_0, u_1, u_2] = [x, y, z]
    fx = 10*u[1] - 10*u[0]
    fy = 28*u[0] - u[0]*u[2] - u[1]
    fz = u[0]*u[1] - 8/3*u[2]
    return [fx, fy, fz]

def lorenz(Tstart, Tend, Ustart, n):
    T, h = linspace(Tstart,Tend, n+1, retstep = True)
    U = zeros((n+1, 3))
    U[0,:] = Ustart

    for i in range(0, n):
        Ka = lorfunction(T[i], U[i])
        Kb = lorfunction(T[i] + h/2, U[i] + h/2*Ka)
        Kc = lorfunction(T[i] + h/2, U[i] + h/2*Kb)
        Kd = lorfunction(T[i] + h, U[i] + h*Kc)
        U[i+1] = U[i] + h/6*(Ka + 2*Kb + 2*Kc + Kd)

    return T,U

print (lorenz(0.0, 100.0, [0,1,0,], 10000))
```

Comment: .. Interestingly, while you *can* catch a `UnicodeError` and parse its `str` result for the position, that is not of much use. I tried `rewind` and then a loop using `readline` to get to the erroneous one, but `readline` is [heavily buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14541010) and no amount of tinkering made it read one line at a time on my system. Anyone else?

Comment: (Saving your text sample as Latin-1 and then opening and reading this with the default UTF-8 encoding is enough to test with.)

Comment: (I must be in Random Mode today.) The *proper* way to avoid a `UnicodeError` is, of course, to make sure you open a text file with its proper `encoding='...'`. But your question is still valid when this proper encoding by all rights should have been UTF8 and thus actually contains an invalid byte.

Answer (score 2):

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 57: invalid continuation byte

The `57` is the byte position of complaint in your Python source file.
In your case it seems to be the position of the `é` in `# Date création fichier`.

`0xe9` is the byte at that position. I recognize it as the [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
(a.k.a. ISO-Latin-1) representation of the character `é`.

So it seems your Python source file is actually encoded in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1),
but the Python interpreter for some reason assumes it to be encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

By the way:
In UTF-8 characters above 128 are encoded by 2 or more bytes,
the first being called the start byte, the others called continuation bytes.
For more explanation see the [UTF-8 examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples).

To understand the error I need to elaborate more.
Consider the bytes `0xe9 0x61 0x74`, as occuring in your Python file:
Decoding the 3 bytes as ISO-8859-1 (being a single-byte encoding) would result in 3 characters: `éat`.
Decoding the same bytes as UTF-8 is more complicated.
The byte `0xe9` (because beginning with the bits `1110`) is a starting byte
to be followed by 2 continuation bytes.
Each continuation byte needs to begin with the bits `10`,
But the next 2 bytes (`0x61 0x74`) violate this condition.
Thus, a *UnicodeError* saying *invalid continuation byte* is thrown.

To avoid this kind of problem you have some alternative options:

- Keep your Python source encoded in ISO-8859-1
  and add the line

  ```
   # -*- coding:iso-8859-1 -*-
  ```

  at the beginning of the file
  as described in [PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#examples).
- Save your Python source in UTF-8.
  and rely on UTF-8 being the default source-encoding of your Python-interpreter.
- Save your Python source in UTF-8.
  and add the line

  ```
   # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
  ```

I would prefer the first or third option.